# db:migrate gives ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_secret_access_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Every time I try to run `db:migrate` or `heroku run console`, I get `ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_secret_access_key`

I have done `heroku config:set` for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Afterwards I run heroku config and see those two and the`S3_BUCKET`correct. Then I run`heroku run console` and I get the error.

I have also went on my IAM management console and I gave my user the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy. Although this does nothing.

I am also using `config/application.yml` from the `figaro` gem to store my keys, but that's no different either.

I'm out of ideas on what to do to fix this, does anyone know what to know?

carrierwave.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
        config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines
        config.fog_credentials = {
            # Configuration for Amazon S3
            :provider => 'AWS',
            :aws_access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
            :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
            :region => 'us-west-2',
            :host => 's3.example.com',
            :endpoint => 'https://s3.example.com:8080'
        }
        config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
        config.fog_public = false # optional, defaults to true
        config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  #   optional, defaults to {}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` but you application reads `S3_ACCESS_KEY` and `S3_SECRET_KEY` environment variables.

Comment: Changing from `S3` to `AWS` fixed it.